# How to use parent() and sibling() together in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 2 divs like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text"  class="input firstName" />
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <button type="button" value="edit" id="Esubmit" class="button">Save</button>
</div>
```

Using the power of `parent()` and `sibling()` in jQuery how can I get the value of "firstname" when the "save" button is clicked.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$('#Esubmit').click(function () {
    var first = $(this).parent().siblings('.content > input#firstName').eq(0);
    alert(first.val());
});
```

I know you can just say

```
var first = $('#firstName').val();
```

But there is a specific reason why I need to do it with siblings and parent.

Comment: Just remember that having multiple ID's in one HTML document is not valid code and will cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a filter selector as an argument of `.siblings()`, not a full selector. Use:

```
var first = $(this).parent().siblings('.content').children('input#firstName');
```

Answer (score 0):

You following code

```
$('#Esubmit').click(function () {
    var first = $(this).parent().siblings('.content').children('input#firstName');// by parent and sibling
    alert(first.val());
});
```

reference [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: `#Esubmit` doesn't seem to have a closest `.content` parent.

Answer (score 0):

Using your DOM structure in the question, you can reference firstName using the following string of jQuery functions:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.content').children('#firstName').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
            $('#Esubmit').click(function () 
            {
                var first = $(this).parent().prev().find('input#firstName');
                alert(first.val());
            });
```